# Console App running as a Windows Service throws an error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, console-application

So I had a console application that waits for a client to press enter and then copies a file from a hard coded location to another location.  As a console application this works great however when I converted it to a windows service I get the following error code when the client presses enter:

```
"Could not connect to http://localhost:8080/myService. TCP error code 10061: 
 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080."
```

I have checked to make sure that the ports are open and that the firewall is not blocking it.  Everything appears to be in the clear so I am confused as to what is going on.  Below I will post my client and host code please take a look at it and let me know if there is something I missed so that I can move forward on this.

This is the Host

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.ServiceModel;
using myServiceLib;

namespace myServiceHost
{
    class Program : ServiceBase
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new Program());
        }

        public Program()
        {
             this.ServiceName = "myService";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);

            using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(myService)))
            {
                serviceHost.Open();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Client

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace myServiceClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        Console.WriteLine("***** Prepairing to transfer files ***** \n");

        using (FileXferClient myMethod = new FileXferClient())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to begin transfer...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            string fileName = "test.txt";
            string sourcePath = @"C:\TestFromC";
            string targetPath = @"C:\TestFromC\Test Folder";

            myMethod.FileXfer(fileName, sourcePath, targetPath);

            Console.WriteLine("File transfer is complete!");
        }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

myServiceLib (this at library with the logic)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace myServiceLib
{
    public class myService : IFileXfer
    {
        public myService()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Awaiting Files...");
        }
        public void FileXfer(string fileName, string sourcePath, string targetPath)
        {
            string passFileName = fileName;
            string passSourcePath = sourcePath;
            string passTargetPath = targetPath;

            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, destFile, true);

            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

                foreach (string s in files)
                {
                    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                    destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace myServiceLib 
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Intertech.com")]
    public interface IFileXfer
    {
        //Transfer files from one the target machine to the destination location
        [OperationContract]
        void FileXfer(string fileName, string sourcePath, string targetPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: "`FileXfer`": syllable-saving-goodness? No. Just pointless.

Comment: Are you sure that server is running before client starts?

Comment: yes the server is indeed running.  I would open up the services.msc and made sure that the process was in there and running before starting the client.

Comment: @Jimmy have no idea how is your code designed but the fact is that client (or part that is responsible for connection) runs before the server is started.

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained it fully and I apologise for the confusion.  The "HOST" is the "Server" which is responsible for the connections and is waiting to recieve a message to begin the file transfer.  The "Client" is the application that sends that call. Looking above I believe the confusion is because I forgot to include the myServiceLib which holds a lot of the logic I am going to update the post with that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the `ServiceHost` immediately after starting it:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

        using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(myService)))
        {
            serviceHost.Open();
        }
    }
```

Because it's inside a `using` statement, it will be disposed (equivalent to calling `Close`) before your `OnStart` method even returns.

Instead, make `serviceHost` a field in the `Program` class, then have:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(myService));
        serviceHost.Open();
    }
```

And

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        serviceHost.Close();

        base.OnStop();
    }
```

Comment: That was it...I feel silly as for not seeing that. Much obliged, you saved me a lot of frustration and head ache.